# C++ Seekp multiple times

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

The Code needs to write some values in a file by going to the specific adresses with seekp. But when i start it only the first Array is written into the file.
The new adresses can be read from the INI like the new values but its just not going to be written in the file. Its for a games save file.

Code:

```
const int noq = 5; 
const int noqd = 4; 
int questData[noqd] = {10, 10, 10, 10};
int adresslist[noqd] ={0x0,0x0,0x0, 0x0}; 
fstream aus("quest1", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::in);   
char buffer[512];
int i;
int j;
int Money, Prize, HRpoints, Map;    
int Mappointer, Moneypointer, PrizePointer, HRpointer;


for (j=0; j <= noq; j++)
{
    sprintf_s(buffer,"%d",j);
    Money = GetPrivateProfileInt(buffer,"RewardMoney", 0, ".\\Settings.ini");
    Prize = GetPrivateProfileInt(buffer,"Questprize", 0 , ".\\Settings.ini");
    HRpoints = GetPrivateProfileInt(buffer,"RewardHRpoints", 0 , ".\\Settings.ini");
    Map = GetPrivateProfileInt(buffer,"Map", 1 , ".\\Settings.ini");


    questData[0] = Money;
    questData[1] = HRpoints;
    questData[2] = Prize;
    questData[3] = Map;

    Moneypointer = GetPrivateProfileInt(buffer,"RewardMoney", 0, ".\\Pointers.ini");
    PrizePointer = GetPrivateProfileInt(buffer,"Questprize", 0 , ".\\Pointers.ini");
    HRpointer = GetPrivateProfileInt(buffer,"RewardHRpoints", 0 , ".\\Pointers.ini");
    Mappointer = GetPrivateProfileInt(buffer,"Map", 1 , ".\\Pointers.ini");
    adresslist[0] = Moneypointer;
    adresslist[1] = HRpointer;
    adresslist[2] = PrizePointer;
    adresslist[3] = Mappointer;


    for (i=0; i<=noqd; i++)
    {
        printf("\n<Adress>\n");
        aus.seekp(0x0);
        aus.seekp(adresslist[i], ios::beg);
        printf("\n<Write>");
        aus.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&questData[i]), sizeof(questData[i])); 
        Beep(1000,100); 
    }



    i = 0;
}
aus.close();
```

}

Comment: To get help with your question, read the following and edit your question accordingly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Apart from the spurious call to seekp(0x0) there's nothing wrong with the code you have posted.  I think we need a [mcve].

Comment: @SamVarshavchik:  If you write `[mcve]` you get the same link with a nicer title.  Oh, and "Snap!"

Comment: How do you read your data?  Did you do a seekg before reading?

Comment: No, i posted my whole code. Its for a game save file but i it is just not working.

Comment: What is the point of the outer loop?  You appear to write the same data every time at the same location.

Comment: Im trying to write data into multiple locations. The outer loop reads to locations inside the file. The inner loop is for writing the data in the file. Its like: Location1:(Data1,Data2,Data3) Location2:(Data1,Data2,Data3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loops are wrong.

```
for (i=0; i<=noqd; i++)
```

This goes 0,1,2,3,4. but your array only goes from 0 to 3.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU. I totaly forgot that an array starts at 0 at this point. I used the same int on the for loop